# How to get an RSS feed of your activity on Khan Academy?

Tags: rss

In Khan Academy, when you view your profile, you're able to see all of your recent activities:
[image: Khan Academy: Recently Completed Activities]

Is there a way to get this information in an RSS feed to incorporate in a personal blog, or other website/webapp?

Comment: Can you see that feed without signing in? If the feed is not public(i.e. if you cannot view that feed without signing in) then it's not possible.

Comment: Under the five icons on the top right section of the page, you have an option to make the profile private or public.  Right now, it's public.  When you visit the profile page, logged out, you don't see the activity section though.

Comment: If the activity is not public, then not possible.